# Folder Picker Issue - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, directory

I am using **msoFileDialogFolderPicker** to get the folder path and folder name by browsing and selecting the required folder, where a dialog box will open and the user have to select the folder by clicking OK in the dialog box.

If a folder is selected and OK is clicked, the full folder path is stored in the variable Folderpth. If cancel is clicked, the variable Folderpth will be blank.

My issue is, if the user clicks OK even without selecting the folder, that particular directory path
is getting stored in the variable Folderpth .

Here is the code i am using,

```
Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With diaFolder
    
    diaFolder.Title = "Select the source folder"
    diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
    
    If diaFolder.Show = -1 Then
    
        Folderpth = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
        
        splitting = Split(Folderpth, "\", 9)

        counter = UBound(splitting)

        foldername = splitting(counter)
        
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Folderpth)
        
            Else
            
                MsgBox "Please select the Source folder"
                
                Folderpth = ""
                
                Exit Sub
                
            End If
        
End With
```

If the user browse to a folder, where its subfolder is his required folder, but without selecting the required folder if he clicks ok, the path captured will be incorrect. I want to over come capturing the folder path without selecting it.

Is it possible

Comment: By not selecting anything, you are selecting the current folder. Why would you want to prevent that?

Comment: Not sure if excel will always open the dialouge at workbook path, but if so, maybe you could do `if Folderpth = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path then Folderpth = Nothing` or something like that.

Comment: @ChristoferWeber That path is used again and it affects the rest of the program that's why.

Comment: Here is an idea. When you launch the `msoFileDialogFolderPicker`, store the initital path in a variable. When the user click ok, match it with the new path. If the paths are same then inform user that the path is same and would he like to continue? Simple as that

Comment: Also, since you are using `With diaFolder`, `diaFolder.Title` should probably just be `.Title`, and same for the others.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks, but what if the user browse from the initial path to a folder, where its subfolder is his required folder, but without selecting the required folder if he clicks ok, the path captured will be incorrect. I want to over come capturing the folder path without selecting it.

Comment: `but what if the user browse from the initial path to a folder` The user has made his choice and it should be respected. As simple as that

Comment: `the path captured will be incorrect.` Then handle that in the code and tell user that the folder he has chosen is incorrect and to rechoose the folder?

Answer (score 1):

### Initial File Name Restriction

- How I (mis)understood your question, this is not what you asked for, but it might help you to achieve the desired result. I played for a while with no result.
- The value of the `InitialPath` variable has to be entered without the trailing path separator (`\`).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub fp()
    
    Dim InitialPath As String
    InitialPath = "C:"

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Source Folder Selection"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = InitialPath & Application.PathSeparator
        Debug.Print "Initial File Name: " & .InitialFileName
        If .Show <> -1 Then
        ' User pressed 'Cancel'.
            MsgBox "Next time please select the source folder"
            Exit Sub
        Else
        ' User pressed 'OK', but didn't change the Initial Path.
            Dim FolderPath As String
            FolderPath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
            If Right(InitialPath, 1) = ":" Then
                InitialPath = InitialPath & Application.PathSeparator
            End If
            If FolderPath = InitialPath Then
                MsgBox "'" & FolderPath & "' is not allowed."
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End With
    
    ' User pressed 'OK' selecting a path different than Initial Path.
    ' Continue...
    Debug.Print "FolderPath: " & FolderPath
    
    ' Either:
    Dim SplitArray As Variant
    SplitArray = Split(FolderPath, Application.PathSeparator)
    Dim FolderName As String
    If UBound(SplitArray) = 1 And SplitArray(0) = "" Then
        FolderName = SplitArray(0)
    Else
        FolderName = SplitArray(UBound(SplitArray))
    End If
    Debug.Print "Split: " & FolderName
    
    'or:
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        FolderName = .getFolder(FolderPath).Name
    End With
    Debug.Print "FileSystemObject: " & FolderName
    
End Sub
```